# Why does prefetching not work for <Link> component in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, prefetch

I read many blogs everyone mentions that Next.js prefetches the Link but it was not working for me.

Here is my chrome network tab:
[image]

that is my code that I tried:

```js
import  Link from 'next/link' 

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div >
          <Link href="/home">
              <a>Home</a>
          </Link>
          <Link href="/About/about">
              <a>About</a>
          </Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Next.js doesn't prefetch pages in development mode, prefetch is a production-only feature.

> **prefetch**
>
> Defaults to `true`. When `true`, `next/link` will prefetch the page
> (denoted by the `href`) in the background. This is useful for improving
> the performance of client-side navigations. Any `<Link />` in the
> viewport (initially or through scroll) will be preloaded.
>
> Prefetch can be disabled by passing `prefetch={false}`. **Prefetching is only enabled in production**.
>
> — [Next.js, Components: `<Link>`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link#prefetch)

Try running your app in production mode instead.

```bash
npm run build && npm run start
```